# How do you say “The brothers have a good relationship.”?

Tags: constructions

For the sentence “The brothers have a good relationship.”, I know we can say

a. Les frères ont de bons rapports.

But can we also say

b. **Les frères ont un bon rapport.**

As this is a simple question, a simple yes or no would be okay.

Comment: « Les frères s'entendent bien. »

Comment: "rapport" in french can also mean intercourse, so I'd avoid this term if no further context is added

Comment: @Lyzvaleska That would be a stretch for me to think of it this way. Not sure about others, but my mind is clearly not set to fall into that rut so easily.

Comment: @Pasunclue — Beaucoup de mots de la vie courante sont récupérés pour leur double sens par les comiques/humoristes. Le *glamour* en est sûrement à la base, mais les sous-entendus grivois sont là pour déniaiser une pudibonderie névrotique.

Comment: @Personne Eh bien celui-là serait bien trop indirect pour moi. *Rapport* a trop de sens outre celui de relation sexuelle pour que je considère celui-là dans mon analyse. Peut-être un humoriste parviendrait-il à m'y amener, mais même là, le doute demeure.

Comment: @Pasunclue — Ce n'est pas un problème d'analyse, mais d'ambiance familière détendue où l'on peut avoir "la langue verte" sans tomber dans la vulgarité. « … déniaiser une pudibonderie névrotique. » consiste à taquiner les personnes ‘psycho-rigides’/qui se donnent une attitude sociale qui ne correspond pas à leur nature profonde … et non les personnes que ce genre de conversation n'intéressent pas.

Comment: @Personne Je dois avouer ne pas vraiment comprendre. Je dis simplement que contrairement à la mise en garde recommendant d'éviter "rapport" à cause d'une possible connotation sexuelle, je n'hésiterais en aucun cas à l'utiliser sans contexte. Des expressions comme «rapports sexuels» ou «maison de rapports» me semblent d'ailleurs assez formelles et fort peu aguichantes.

Comment: @Pasunclue — C'est surtout comment la phrase que vous croyez innocente peut être entendue dans certains milieux hexagonaux qui va révéler votre méconnaissance des codes sociaux de vos interlocuteurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @Personne in the comments, you can use the verb [*s'entendre*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_entendre/29881).

> Les deux frères s'entendent bien.

As stated in the comments, *rapport* can also mean intercourse in French, so it could be ambiguous to use this without adding more context. However, it is a correct usage ([see the CNRTL definition, section **III.E.**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/rapport)), and it can work very well, for example:

> Les deux frères travaillent ensemble et ont de bons rapports professionnels.

or

> Malgré la séparation durant leur enfance, les deux frères sont restés en bon rapports.

However, to answer your question, I don't think it makes sense to use *rapport* as a singular because it designates the (multiple) interactions two people can have with each other. If you wish to use a singular word, use *relation*, which defines the link itself between two people (it can actually also be used in its plural form but let's not go too deep into details).

Comment: Would the occasional singular «rapport» *(la compagnie a un bon rapport avec la population)* be an influence from the more commonly singular «relation» *(la compagnie a une bonne relation avec la communauté)*?

Comment: It would make sense. Maybe it even makes it a correct usage, although not intuitive from my point of view.

Comment: Yeah same here. I'm not sure about the correctness of it. And definitely not something I would ever transfer to the context of actual people, as opposed to the “entities” that companies or communities are.

Comment: @Reyedy Thank you so much for your help! 

Comment: @Reyedy (1) I’m happy to accept « Les frère ont un bonne relation. »  For the sentence “The brothers have a good relationship with their biological mother.”, could I therefore say  **(a) « Les frères ont un bonnes rapports avec leur mère biologique. »**

Comment: @Reyedy et **(b) « Les frères ont une bonne relation avec leur mère biologique. »**?

Comment: So first of all, be careful with the gender of nouns: relation is **feminine** (*une relation*) and rapport is **masculine** (*un rapport*). Also, for your sentence (a), you used the plural with the article "un", which is used for singular nouns. So for this sentence, a correct usage would be *"Les frères ont de bons rapports avec leur mère biologique"*. And your sentence (b) is correct, good job! I personally have a preference for the (a) in this context though. :)

Comment: @Reyedy Lol thank you for being so kind!  This is really helpful thank you!!! 

Comment: Glad I could help. If I answered your question properly, you can click on the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as "accepted". Cheers :)